# CentOS VM 3972 Segmentation Fault

Tags: centos, cluster, matlab

I'm trying to install MATLAB 2012 on CentOS 5.8 running on a VM cluster. I was able to mount the .iso file, but when I run `./install`, it was unable to write to `/tmp` giving the error, "no space on device".

So after running the command:

```
mount -o mode=1777,nosuid,nodev -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp
```

I get the following:

```
[root@pub121 iso]# df -H /tmp
Filesystem             Size   Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                  2.2G      0   2.2G   0% /tmp
```

and `/etc/fstab` looks like this:

```
[root@pub121 iso]# cat /etc/fstab
LABEL=/                 /                       ext3    defaults        1 1
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   size=10g        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
LABEL=SWAP-xvda2        swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

When I install MATLAB, the following message is shown:

```
Preparing installation files ...
Installing ...
./install: line 713:  3972 Segmentation fault      
/tmp/mathworks_3936/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/bin/java -splash:"/mnt/iso/java/splash.png"-Djava.ext.dirs=/tmp/mathworks_3936/sys/java/jre/glnx86/jre/lib/ext:/tmp/mathworks_3936/java/jar:/tmp/mathworks_3936/java/jarext:/tmp/mathworks_3936/java/jarext/axis2/:/tmp/mathworks_3936/java/jarext/guice/:/tmp/mathworks_3936/java/jarext/webservices/ com/mathworks/professionalinstaller/Launcher -root "/mnt/iso" -tmpdir "/tmp/mathworks_3936"
```

Any suggestions?

[EDIT]

I have the option to provide an alternate location instead of /tmp in the install script. However, I am running CentOS as an MPICH2 cluster with 8 nodes and there is limited space as shown

```
[root@pub121 ~]# df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1             7103744   7095484         0 100% /
tmpfs                 10485760         0  10485760   0% /dev/shm
/home/Matlab_Unix_2012a/ml2012au.iso
                   5212274   5212274         0 100% /mnt/iso
tmpfs                  2097244         0   2097244   0% /tmp
```

Is it possible to run the install script with this configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take a look at the `./install` script and see if you cannot override the location that it's using as `/tmp`. Your options may include:

1. Script allows a variable being set to override the default location.
2. Modify the script yourself to override the location.
3. Create a symbolic link inside the `/tmp` directory that points to a directory outside of `/tmp`.

#### Not enough space to do the install?

Here are a couple of approaches if you find you don't have enough space to either install or host the application locally on the system where you'd like to run it.

1. If you find yourself not having enough space to do the install I would recommend the following approach. You can install the software on another system that you do have enough space on, and then `rsync` or `scp` the resulting installation over to system that you ultimately want it on.
2. Install the software on another "remote" system and then use either automounting or FUSE to "mount" the directory where the software's been "locally" on the system where you want to run MATLAB.

Comment: I have the option to provide an alternate location instead of /tmp in the install script. However, I am running CentOS as an MPICH2 cluster with 8 nodes and there is limited space as shown `/dev/xvda1   7103744    100% /tmpfs  10485760  0% /dev/shm
/home/Matlab_Unix_2012a/ml2012au.iso
                       5212274   5212274         0 100% /mnt/iso
tmpfs                  2097244         0   2097244   0% /tmp
`  Is it possible to run the install script?

Comment: @Sumit - a couple of alternatives.